# Inserting into a database in Android is failing

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

So I'm trying to insert values in a table that has 2 columns, one for question id and another for the question text. Here is how I'm inserting it:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(HealthyDroidQuizHelper.COLUMN_ID, 1);
values.put(HealthyDroidQuizHelper.COLUMN_QUESTION, "How are you feeling?");
database.insert(HealthyDroidQuizHelper.TABLE_QUESTION, null, values);
```

The method returns -1, so it failed. I've also tried using the database.execSQL() method by hard coding my insert statement into a string but that fails and ends up crashing the application. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is how I'm creating the table

```
private static String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION = "create table "
        + TABLE_QUESTION + "( " + COLUMN_ID 
        + " integer primary key, " + COLUMN_QUESTION + " text not null);";

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
        //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ANSWER);
        //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ASSOCIATION);
    }
```

Here is the updated Logcat output

```
05-07 18:53:37.762: W/KeyCharacterMap(213): No keyboard for id 0
05-07 18:53:37.772: W/KeyCharacterMap(213): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213): Error inserting question=What is your name? _id=2
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table question has no column named question: , while compiling: INSERT INTO question(question, _id) VALUES(?, ?);
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1027)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1413)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1286)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at ca.bcit.comp4900.QuestionDataSource.storeQuestion(QuestionDataSource.java:56)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at ca.bcit.comp4900.TestDatabaseActivity.changeText(TestDatabaseActivity.java:38)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at ca.bcit.comp4900.TestDatabaseActivity.onClick(TestDatabaseActivity.java:60)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-07 18:53:38.902: E/Database(213):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Quite a bit, I don't really understand all its saying.

Comment: If you post it, then we can help you interpret it.

Comment: heh.. yeah, the error is that you've written "COLUMN_QUESTION" as the name for the column right into the string. just a typing error i presume?

Comment: I can't believe I did that >_>. I fixed that up, but the method is still returning -1

Comment: time to update your stack trace in that case :)

Comment: did you also remember to either uninstall the app before reinstalling it *or* dropping the database and recreating it *or* writing the necessary ALTER TABLE statements in your SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: I haven't been dropping my database, but I have been rebooting the Android Emulator

Comment: uninstall / reinstall the app from your emulator. Maybe you created the database before some modifications (ex. you forgot to create  question column) and therefore you get this error

Comment: Alright, everything is fixed up! Thanks Jens and Murat for your help =]. Do you recommend I drop all the tables and recreate them before doing anything else during development?

Answer (score 0):

Is the column_id an auto-increment field?  If so, pass its value as null.  Then sqlite will assign the next number for you.  If it's an auto-increment and you're passing a value, you're likely getting a duplicate key failure.

Comment: @Strata - Is there any reason not to use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as the definition for your id?

Comment: Yes, the questionId is actually going to be the number of the question, which is a data member in the question class

Answer (score 0):

What is your DB scheme looks like? Have you specified ID column as "autogenerated"?

Comment: I edited the question to show the schema (couldn't figure out how to post code cleanly in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your table create statement is using the literal "COLUMN_QUESTION" as the column name, not the assigned value to it, which is presumably simply "question".  Remove `COLUMN_QUESTION` from the string literal to make sure its value is used instead of the literal string.

Comment: I changed it so the variable COLUMN_QUESTION is used, but I'm still getting an insertion error

Comment: @Strata Is the table creation happening in the `HealthyDroidQuizHelper` class?  Maybe you have two similarly named constants defined that (perhaps due to a typo) don't have the same value.